# How does Stack Overflow make its data appear in Google searches so quickly?

Tags: discussion, meta

As a web developer, I'm really curious to know how Stack Overflow maintains its page data.

It seems that Google is indexing SO pages so quickly, and most of the content is loading based on AJAX or Websocket calls on these pages.

How is Google crawling this Ajax data, then? Or is having the post title in the URL doing all the magic itself?

Comment: They probably have a employee watching http://stackoverflow.com/questions on the "newest" tab, entering the data as it comes along. (_This employee may or may not be of flesh and blood_)

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9726) Also see [How does StackOverflow get indexed by Google in such as fast manner?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98083), all Google does is load the sitemap. Several times a second.

Comment: [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome)? ;)